# Show the cart icon only if it exists and it isn't empty

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm looking for an easy way to show on my template a cart icon only if the **cart has 1 or more elements** (Drupal 8, commerce 2.x); I've tried with a view, but I had problems to identify the cart associated to the current (normally anonymous) user.

Does that easy way exist?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've searched on Commerce 2.x docs, but I didn't find anything about the feature I'd like to implement. (I don't want to show the cart, only show an icon when the cart exists and has items.)

I've also used suggestions found on [How do I count the number of products in cart programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249398/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-products-in-cart-programmatically) and I was able to create a twig variable using theme preprocess function, but the variable is never updated. Is it mandatory to develop a module?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know any module that does this but it is simple to do in your theme

Add this to your `THEMENAME.theme`

```php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'commerce_cart') {
    if ($variables['content']['#count'] == 0) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'visually-hidden';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it soon